# How to format string from int64 with fixed 2 decimal points?

Tags: string-formatting, mixed

i'm working with mixed code and i need to display an int value (that represents an amount) with 2 decimal points.

for example: 12366 ==> "123.66", 40 ==> "0.40" , 415 ==> "4.15"

in native c++ i could do:

```
__int64 sum = 12366;

char buff[20];
sprintf(buff, "%0.2Lf", (long double)sum / 100.0);
MyString sumStr(buff); //this is similar to std::string
```

How do i do it in c# (or mixed code)? can it be done with String.Format?

```
__int64 sum = 12366;
String^ sumStr = String::Format("?", sum);
```

i tried looking in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx but i couldn't find anything that will help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok. found it
i should be doing this:

```
__int64 sum = 12366;
Decimal tmp = ((Decimal )sum / 100);
String^ sumStr = String::Format("{0.00}", tmp);
```